# Trying to run php files which have been created by svn hook with owner nobody, suphp enabled

Tags: svn, permissions, hook, suphp

I have created a svn repository hook which will update a working copy on the server (main dev version) depending on directory. This is now working properly, but only if the working copy is owned by nobody. Problem with this is that with suphp enabled php files owned by nobody cant be executed.

I dont know how to get round this issue as the subversion hook will always run under the same user - nobody, but I need the hook to work as well as the files to be executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the best solution is, because we do not know your security needs. In my opinion, suPHP is not necessary in a development environment. So switching off suPHP might be acceptable.

You could tell suPHP to execute PHP scripts under a different user using the `suPHP_UserGroup` directive (see [suPHP Apache module configuration](http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=apache/CONFIG) for details).

Comment: I am going to disable suPHP, I totally agree with you regarding its necessity in a development environment.